# SQL Server stored procedure - A severe error occurred in the current command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having an unusual error with a stored procedure I've wrote to generate telephony statistics. I'm running this sproc on a SQL Server 2005 clustered environment. The procedure gets called around 40 times sequentially (once per call queue) to populate a temp table and then insert this temp table into a table which stores one line per day per queue.

I understand that there is a hotfix to apply to the sql boxes however I wanted to check if there was anything wrong with my sproc before getting the network lads to install patches etc

The main sproc can be seen below (its a lengthy code nightmare). It uses 5 views which are connected to the main telephony database via a linked server (its a Cisco UCCX telephony system).

The error I'm experiencing is as follows:

---

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred in the current command. The results, if any,
>   should be discarded
>   Msg 0, Level 20, Stata 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred in the current command. The results, if any,
>   should be discarded

---

**PROCEDURE WHICH CALLS THE MAIN STORED PROCEDURE**

```
-- North
EXEC [dbo].[SP_GetStatsMain_ByCSQName] @starttime = @OfficeOpen, @endtime = @OfficeClose, @queue = N'CSQ-N003A', @date = @runDate
EXEC [dbo].[SP_GetStatsMain_ByCSQName] @starttime = @OfficeOpen, @endtime = @OfficeClose, @queue = N'CSQ-N004A', @date = @runDate
EXEC [dbo].[SP_GetStatsMain_ByCSQName] @starttime = @OfficeOpen, @endtime = @OfficeClose, @queue = N'CSQ-N005A', @date = @runDate
```

---

**MAIN STORED PROCEDURE**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetStatsMain_ByCSQName]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @starttime DATETIME, 
    @endtime DATETIME, 
    @queue varchar(50),
    @date DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME/*, @date DATETIME
    set @date = getdate()-1*/
    set @start = DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, 0, @starttime), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date)))
    set @end = DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, 0, @endtime), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date)))

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    [CSQName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Presented] [int] NULL,
    [Handled] [int] NULL,
    [Abandonded] [int] NULL,
    [Dequeued] [int] NULL,
    [HandledSLA] [float] NULL,
    [AbandondedSLA] [float] NULL,
    [AvgTalkTime] [float] NULL,
    [AvgWaitTime] [float] NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into #Temp([CSQName])
SELECT    DISTINCT CSQ.CSQName
FROM         CSQ INNER JOIN Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.CSQName
WHERE     ((dateInactive IS NULL) 
OR (dateInactive < GETDATE() - 1)) AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
SET [Date] = dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,@Date))

UPDATE #temp
SET [Presented] = 0,
    [Handled] = 0,
    [Abandonded] = 0,
    [Dequeued] = 0,
    [HandledSLA] = 0,
    [AbandondedSLA] = 0,
    [AvgTalkTime] = 0,
    [AvgWaitTime] = 0

UPDATE #temp
      SET Handled =
            (
              SELECT COUNT(CQD.targetType)
              FROM ACD 
                  INNER JOIN CCD ON ACD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum 
                        AND ACD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID 
                        AND ACD.profileID = CCD.profileID 
                  INNER JOIN CQD ON ACD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID 
                        AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum 
                        AND ACD.profileID = CQD.profileID 
                        AND ACD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID 
                  INNER JOIN CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID 
                        AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID 
                  INNER JOIN Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname 
                  INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
              WHERE     
                  (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) 
                  AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) 
                  AND (CCD.contactDisposition = 2) 
                  AND (ACD.talkTime > 0) 
                  AND (CQD.targetType = 0) 
                  AND (CQD.disposition = 2) 
                  AND Queues.csqname = @queue
            )
      FROM ACD 
            INNER JOIN CCD ON ACD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum 
                  AND ACD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID 
                  AND ACD.profileID = CCD.profileID 
            INNER JOIN CQD ON ACD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID 
                  AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum 
                  AND ACD.profileID = CQD.profileID 
                  AND ACD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID 
            INNER JOIN CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID 
                  AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID 
            INNER JOIN Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname 
            INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
        WHERE     
            (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) 
            AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) 
            AND (CCD.contactDisposition = 2) 
            AND (ACD.talkTime > 0) 
            AND (CQD.targetType = 0) 
            AND (CQD.disposition = 2) 
            AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
      SET Presented =
            (
            SELECT     COUNT(CQD.sessionID) AS [Calls Presented]
            FROM         CQD INNER JOIN
                                  CCD ON CQD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND CQD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum AND CQD.profileID = CCD.profileID AND 
                                  CQD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID INNER JOIN
                                  CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                                  Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
            WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))
            AND Queues.csqname = @queue
            )
            FROM         CQD INNER JOIN
                                  CCD ON CQD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND CQD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum AND CQD.profileID = CCD.profileID AND 
                                  CQD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID INNER JOIN
                                  CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                                  Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
            WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))
            AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
      SET Abandonded =
            (
            SELECT     COUNT(CQD.sessionSeqNum) AS [Calls Abandonded]
            FROM         CCD INNER JOIN
                                  CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
                                  CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
                                  CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                                  Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
            WHERE     (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 1) AND (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))
            AND Queues.csqname = @queue
            )
            FROM CCD INNER JOIN
                                  CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
                                  CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
                                  CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                                  Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
            WHERE     (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 1) AND (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))
            AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
    SET Dequeued =
        (
        SELECT     COUNT(CQD.sessionSeqNum) AS [Calls Dequeued]
        FROM         CCD INNER JOIN
                              CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
                              CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
                              CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                              Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName

        WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))  
                              AND (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 3)
        AND Queues.csqname = @queue
        )
        FROM CCD INNER JOIN
                              CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
                              CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
                              CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                              Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName

        WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))  
                              AND (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 3)
        AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
    SET AbandondedSLA =
        (
        SELECT     COUNT(CQD.sessionSeqNum) AS [Calls Abandonded SLA]
        FROM         CCD INNER JOIN
                              CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
                              CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
                              CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                              Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
        WHERE     (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 1) AND (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))
        AND (CQD.metServiceLevel =1)
        AND Queues.csqname = @queue
        )
        FROM CCD INNER JOIN
                              CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
                              CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
                              CSQ ON CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID AND CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID INNER JOIN
                              Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
        WHERE     (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 1) AND (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102))
        AND (CQD.metServiceLevel =1)
        AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
    SET HandledSLA = 
        (
SELECT     COUNT(CQD.targetType) AS [Calls Handled SLA]
FROM         ACD INNER JOIN
                      CCD ON ACD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID AND 
                      ACD.profileID = CCD.profileID INNER JOIN
                      CQD ON ACD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.profileID = CQD.profileID AND 
                      ACD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID INNER JOIN
                      CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID INNER JOIN
                      Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) AND
                       (CCD.contactDisposition = 2) AND (ACD.talkTime > 0) AND (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 2) AND (CQD.metServiceLevel = 1)
AND Queues.csqname = @queue
)
FROM         ACD INNER JOIN
                      CCD ON ACD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID AND 
                      ACD.profileID = CCD.profileID INNER JOIN
                      CQD ON ACD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.profileID = CQD.profileID AND 
                      ACD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID INNER JOIN
                      CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID INNER JOIN
                      Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) AND
                       (CCD.contactDisposition = 2) AND (ACD.talkTime > 0) AND (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 2) AND (CQD.metServiceLevel = 1)
AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
    SET AvgTalkTime = 
        (
        SELECT     (SUM(CQD.queueTime)/Count(CQD.queueTime)) AS [AverageQueueTime]
        FROM         CCD INNER JOIN
                              CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
                              CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
                              CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID INNER JOIN
                              Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
        WHERE     (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) AND Queues.csqname = @queue
        )
        FROM CCD INNER JOIN
        CQD ON CCD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND CCD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND CCD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID AND 
        CCD.profileID = CQD.profileID INNER JOIN
        CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID INNER JOIN
        Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
        WHERE     (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) AND Queues.csqname = @queue

UPDATE #temp
    SET AvgWaitTime = 
        (
        SELECT    (SUM(ACD.talkTime) / COUNT(CQD.targetType)) AS [AverageTalkTime]
        FROM         ACD INNER JOIN
                              CCD ON ACD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID AND 
                              ACD.profileID = CCD.profileID INNER JOIN
                              CQD ON ACD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.profileID = CQD.profileID AND 
                              ACD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID INNER JOIN
                              CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID INNER JOIN
                              Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
        WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) AND
                               (CCD.contactDisposition = 2) AND (ACD.talkTime > 0) AND (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 2)
        AND Queues.csqname = @queue
        )
        FROM         ACD INNER JOIN
                              CCD ON ACD.sessionID = CCD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CCD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.nodeID = CCD.nodeID AND 
                              ACD.profileID = CCD.profileID INNER JOIN
                              CQD ON ACD.sessionID = CQD.sessionID AND ACD.sessionSeqNum = CQD.sessionSeqNum AND ACD.profileID = CQD.profileID AND 
                              ACD.nodeID = CQD.nodeID INNER JOIN
                              CSQ ON CQD.targetID = CSQ.recordID AND CQD.profileID = CSQ.profileID INNER JOIN
                              Queues ON CSQ.CSQName = Queues.csqname INNER JOIN #temp on CSQ.CSQName = #Temp.CSQName
        WHERE     (CCD.startDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, @start, 102)) AND (CCD.startDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, @end, 102)) AND
                               (CCD.contactDisposition = 2) AND (ACD.talkTime > 0) AND (CQD.targetType = 0) AND (CQD.disposition = 2)
        AND Queues.csqname = @queue

INSERT INTO [db_cra].[dbo].[CallData]
           ([CSQName]
           ,[Presented]
           ,[Handled]
           ,[Abandonded]
           ,[Dequeued]
           ,[HandledSLA]
           ,[AbandondedSLA]
           ,[AvgTalkTime]
           ,[AvgWaitTime]
           ,[Date])
SELECT * FROM #Temp

END
```

Comment: Do the SQL Server logs or error message give any additional details? e.g. Assert Failed or something.

Comment: Off topic to the question, but is this bit `OR (dateInactive < GETDATE() - 1)) ` (when initially populating `#Temp`) correct, given that everything else is dealing with the @date parameter that's been passed in.

Comment: There are so many bits to re-write here, I don't know where to start. For instance, if `@starttime` is, as it's name implies, just a time (with the date part defaulted to `19000101`), then `@start` adds that time onto the date passed in as `@date`. But, everywhere that `@start` is used, it's inside a `CONVERT` function that's going to remove the time component. The identical repeating queries (one in the `SET`, the other in the `FROM`) shouldn't be necessary. Near identical queries should be replaceable by `COUNT(CASE WHEN Conditiion1 is true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - cheers for that. It should be using the parameter rather than getdate()-1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Also, I'm pretty much a n00b at SQL, so this is the first albeit dodgy process for gettign the data I need. I worked with a consultant *shudder* tp get the repeating SET FROM stuff working, as I was origianlly usign a group by. I'm not too sure what you mean about the near identical queries? 

Anyway, I think one of the network chaps are going to patch and hotfix the cluster :) but I still would like to rewrite this eventually!

Comment: Yeah, you could definitely rewrite this into a single statement and still maintain readability :)